# Custom notification on React Native using react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I am implementing push notifications in my application using the react-native-firebase library, but I have a question. I need to mount custom notifications in my app, and assemble them from React without the server sending me Title / Body, I need these notifications with the app in the background and fully closed.

I made the following attempt, but to no avail.

In my index I registered my class

```
  AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask(
  "RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage",
  () => bgMessaging
 );
```

In my JS class, I treat the following way

```
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";

import type { NotificationOpen } from "react-native-firebase";

export default async (notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
  if (notificationOpen) {
    const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
      .setTitle("Android Notification Actions")
      .setBody("Action Body")
      .setNotificationId("notification-action")
      .setSound("default")
      .android.setChannelId("notification-action")
      .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.Max);
    // Build an action
    const action = new firebase.notifications.Android.Action(
      "snooze",
      "ic_launcher",
      "My Test Action"
    );
    // This is the important line
    action.setShowUserInterface(false);
    // Add the action to the notification
    notification.android.addAction(action);

    // Display the notification
    firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
  }

  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

But I was not successful. Push notifications sent from firebase with fixed title and body work normally.

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try with below,

- Change `.setNotificationId("notification-action")` to `.setNotificationId(notificationOpen.notification.notificationId)`
- Change `.android.setChannelId("notification-action")` to `.android.setChannelId(notificationOpen.notification.android.channelId)`